# Yii2 preferred way to set 'class'

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2 codebase, I saw 2 different types of config declaration:

One way with `CLASS_NAME::class`

```
'options' => ['class' => OptionsAction::class],
```

Another way with full string representation

```
'options' => ['class' => 'yii\rest\OptionsAction'],
```

Which way is preferable and why?

Comment: I've seen both, but am using ::class since it is refactor friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways might be used, but the better way is the declaration with help `::class` because:

- it makes dependencies more clear. All dependencies will declare one place - in USE section.
- it makes an ability to validation of code with help IDE. If there is a class name in a string then IDE can't analyze this string and it means IDE can't validate your code
- it makes refactoring of existing code more usability. If all dependencies will declare in one place and they won't be contained in strings you won't look for a necessary declaration of a class name in all code and you can apply tools of your IDE to code refactoring

Comment: In addition - using `::class` does not trigger autoloading.